# Paramaterized Query With SQL Data Reader C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I know that non parameterized queries are frowned upon because of SQL injection. Well, I have a lot of queries in my application that are susceptible to SQL injection. I just can't seem to wrap my head around doing it with `SqlDataReader`. I am able to do it with `ExecuteNonQuery` just not `SQLDataReader`.

Can someone give me some pointers and or examples of the best way to do this, the query is executing and returning exactly what it should, I just want to make it as secure as possible....

Code:

```
string myQuery = "Select [shoeSize] AS 'Shoe Size', [shoeBrand] AS 'Shoe Brand' FROM [myTable] "
                 + "WHERE [customerName] = '" + customer + "' AND " + "[customerPin] = '" + customerID + "'";

 sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(myQuery, conn);
 sqlCmd.Connection.Open();
 SqlDataReader rdr2 = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

  if (rdr2.HasRows)
     {
        rdr2.Read();

        shoeSize= rdr2["Shoe Size"].ToString();       
        shoeBrand= rdr2["Shoe Brand"].ToString();
     }
     conn.close();
```

Comment: You shouldn't use string concatenation or string formatting for generate sql query text, instead use sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(...)

Comment: *frowned upon* is the euphemism of the year...

Comment: @oleg Did you even read his question?

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar yes, what's wrong?

Comment: @Oleg His question is how to turn non-parameterized queries into parameterized queries and you tell him not to use string concatenation/formatting to build queries? That leads me to the impression that you did either not read or understand what he's asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There you go

```
string myQuery = "Select [shoeSize] AS 'Shoe Size', [shoeBrand] AS 'Shoe Brand' FROM [myTable] "
                 + "WHERE [customerName] = @customerName AND [customerPin] = @customerID"

 sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(myQuery, conn);
 sqlCmd.Connection.Open();
 sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerName", customerName);
 sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerID", customerID");
 --rest stays the same as before
```

Whereas @customerName and @customerID are now your parameters. So even if the customer's name should be something like "Bigler, Fabian' DROP TABLE [myTable]" it will not work. It completely removes the possibility of "evil" input changing the meaning of your query.

Non-parameterized queries are not simply 'frowned upon'. It can be disastrous for you, your company and - of course - your customer.

Comment: And yet people release nhibernate and entity framework based applications to live still. Sigh.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
        string myQuery = "Select [shoeSize] AS 'Shoe Size', [shoeBrand] AS 'Shoe Brand' FROM [myTable] "
              + "WHERE [customerName] = @customerName AND [customerPin] = @customerPin";

        sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(myQuery, conn);
        sqlCmd.Connection.Open();
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@customerName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = customer;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@customerPin", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = customerID;
        SqlDataReader rdr2 = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (rdr2.HasRows)
        {
            rdr2.Read();

            shoeSize = rdr2["Shoe Size"].ToString();
            shoeBrand = rdr2["Shoe Brand"].ToString();
        }
        conn.close();
```